# Why is the last bracket a invalid character error

Tags: java

Originally my error with was with the last bracket, the last bracket in the code shown below says invalid character delete this token and it would not save and I got an error:

"Save could not be completed. Try File > Save As... if the problem persists. Reason: Some characters cannot be mapped using the "Cp1252" character encoding. Either change the encoding or remove the characters which are not supported by the "Cp1252" character encoding."

This code worked fine until I called this method to another class, I figured that was the problem so I commented the call out but the error remained.

I already converted this to a UTF-8 and the error with the bracket as an invalid character is still there.

I am using Eclispe.

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks!

```
public void render(int xPos, int yPos, int tile, int color, boolean mirrorX, boolean mirrorY)   
{

    xPos -= xOff;
    yPos -= yOff;

    int xTile = tile % 32;
    int yTile = tile / 32;
    int tileOffset = (xTile << 3) + (yTile << 3) * sheet.width;

    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
    {

        if (y + yPos < 0 || y + yPos >= height)
        {
            continue;
        }
        int ySheet = y;
        if (mirrorY)
        {
            ySheet = 7-y;
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            if (x + xPos < 0 || x + xPos >= width)
            {
                continue;
            }
            int xSheet = x;
            if (mirrorX)
            {
                xSheet = 7-x;
            }
            int col = (color >> (sheet.pixels[xSheet + ySheet * sheet.width + tileOffset] * 8)) & 255;
            if (col < 255)
            {
                pixels[(x + xPos) + (y + yPos) * width] = col;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The whole text you posted here is plain ASCII. Try to save that text back into Eclipse. Narrow down the problem by trying to save only parts of the text, then try to understand which parts fail and why.

Comment: UTF-8 is not the same as Cp1252. Instead of mapping to UTF-8, map to Cp1252. Alternatively, change the source encoding in Eclipse's settings

Answer (score 0):

I converted the file back to Cp1252 and four characters showed up after the bracket, I don't know where they came from but at least my error is fixed.